# How to read a specific string from a file and save the whole line in another file in Bash Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, redhat

I have a file which contains many lines. Each line contains strings and numbers. My script should read the `file` and when a specific word is matched, it should save the complete line. For example one of the line contains: `Computera abc23`, when the script should find the word `Computera` in any line it should save the whole line i.e `Computera abc23`. The line should be saved in `file1`.
Similarly another line in the `file` contains word `machine1`, when the script should see the word `machine1` it should save that line in `file1`

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
f="home/c/file.txt"
n=$(cat "$f")
echo "${n} >| /home/c/file1.txt"
```

My code reads and saves all the text from `file` to `file1` But I would like to save only those lines where a specific word is matched

Comment: Use [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html): `grep "$word" "$file" > /home/c/file1.txt`

Comment: @joshmeranda. thanks. But how i save the complete line which contains the word?

Comment: The great thing about `grep` is that it does that for for you! You can tell it to only output the matching content, but by default it outputs the matching line.

Comment: @joshmeranda If a line contains 5 words and a specific word is matched in this line, all 5 words will be saved?

Comment: yes, the whole line will be matched. You can read more about grep and how to use it [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) or by running `man grep`

Comment: @joshmeranda. Thank for the reply. How if I have to save multiple lines. For example if  word1 is matched in line 5 and word2 is matched in line 9, how both lines can be saved in file1? Could you please comment?

Comment: There are a few ways the simplest is to combine into a single pattern `grep 'word1|wod2' file` or you can separate them `grep -e word1 -e word2 file` please see the documentation I've sent you it explains all the way you can you grep in more depth than I could

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this:

```
cat file | grep [pattern] | awk '{ print $number-of-column }' >> file1
```

I recommend reading about both `cut` and `awk` and how you can use them with `grep` command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).